# Rails generate a controller with different inheritance than Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, inheritance, controllers

Anybody know a shortcut way of generating a controller that inherits from something different than ApplicationController?

I currently run:

```
rails g controller Admin::Food
```

but it creates

```
class Admin::FoodsController < ApplicationController
```

when I actually want:

```
class Admin::FoodsController < AdminController
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Rails controller generator will not allow you to specify the superclass. You will need to edit this file and set the superclass manually.